# Using pandas.melt to get all values for all variables

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df

```
print(df1)
                        var0             var1  var2              var3
0                       Andr               HP    20               132
1                       Valr             Hone    21               542
2                        Kor             Star    12               623
```

I want to get all values for every variable in a 2 row table like so:

```
        var value
0      var0  Andr      
1      var1    HP
2      var2    20
3      var3   132
4      var0  Valr
5      var1  Hone
...
```

I've tried using pandas.melt like this:

`pd.melt(df1, id_vars =['var0'], value_vars =['var1'])`

but this requires defining the columns used.

Is there any way to get the desired output without strictly defining which columns to use with **pandas.melt** or **pandas.wide_to_long**?

Comment: `df.melt()` works for me ?

Comment: @Umar.H this also works, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see [pd.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) doc

```
pd.melt(df, var_name='var', ignore_index=False).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
     var value
0   var0  Andr
1   var1    HP
2   var2    20
3   var3   132
4   var0  Valr
5   var1  Hone
6   var2    21
7   var3   542
8   var0   Kor
9   var1  Star
10  var2    12
11  var3   623
```